# How can I get a Deedle DataFrame from a HttpResponseWithStream?

Tags: http, download, f#, deedle

I wrote a function that downloads data from a service and saves it to a Deedle DataFrame:

```
/// Downloads data from EOD Historical Data for one stock.
let downloadFromEOD (storageDataPath: string) (symbol: string) : unit =

    // Token for the EOD service
    let apiToken = "9999999999999"

    let endStr = "?api_token=" + apiToken + "&period=d&order=d"

    printfn "Downloading symbol %s" symbol 

    let url = @"http://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/eod/" + symbol + endStr

    // The data is saved in a temporary file
    let lines : HttpResponseWithStream = Http.RequestStream(url)
    let tempPath : string = storageDataPath + @"temp\" + symbol + ".csv"
    let fileStream : FileStream = File.Create(tempPath)
    lines.ResponseStream.CopyTo(fileStream)
    fileStream.Close()

    let df : Frame<DateTime,string> =
        File.ReadLines(tempPath)
        |> List.ofSeq
        |> List.tail
        |> List.filter (fun str -> str.Contains ",")
        |> List.map eODRowFoo // not relevant for this SO question
        |> Frame.ofRows

    let path = storageDataPath + symbol + ".csv"

    FrameExtensions.SaveCsv(df, path, includeRowKeys=true, keyNames=["Date"])
```

The function calls `Http.RequestStream` to calculate `lines`, copies `lines` to a path and then reads the file and converts the data to a `Deedle DataFrame`.

I wonder if there is a way to avoid having to write the data to a file and then reading it. Can one generate some kind of object starting from a `HttpResponseWithStream` that can be somehow converted into a `DataFrame` in a less contrived way?

Comment: Take a look at the Input/output section of the [ReadCsv](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/reference/deedle-f__frame_extensions.html) docs. You should be able to use a TextReader stream, directly read from the web resource, or pass some sort of Streamreader.

Comment: @s952163 - Thanks. After doing some research I was able to do what I wanted using `Http.RequestString(url)`. I will also investigate your suggestions.